# How to list all references?

Tags: bibtex

Newbie here, trying to finish a dissertation with tufte-book.

I need to print all the contents of a .bib file in the bibliography; the chapters contain no citations (the document was culled from a Markdown file prepared for the web).

How do I do this? Many hours have been wasted trying to solve this seemingly simple task...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Insert a `\nocite{*}` command

Answer (score 3):

You should insert the instruction

```
\nocite{*}
```

somewhere in the document.

Comment: Hallelujah! And to get rid of the numbers and put it in Chicago Author-Date format?

Comment: @christopher - Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: Chicago Author-Date, preferably with no numbers! Thanks a million.

Comment: In short, you don't have a bibliography style so far? Is there no `\bibliographystyle` directive in your document?

Comment: I was using `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` but that is not the right format.

Comment: If you want Chicago-style formatting and citation call-outs, load the `chicago` package *and* specify the `chicago` bibliography style. Be sure to recompile fully (LaTeX-BibTEX-LaTeX-LaTeX) to fully propagate the change.

Comment: @Mico,  which \bibliographystyle{...} supports \nocite{*}??? chicago not works....